# html2canvas for div small and need large image as high resolution image contain in it?

Tags: html2canvas

I have created html div (ie. 100X100) element that contains high resolution image(400X400)  inside it. and when capture it generates image with same display on web page(100X100) i want to generate image larger(200X200) than div element. I cannot understand how can it possible.. can help me, thanks advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/WbsZp/).

The upper div is an image 400x400, shrunk to 100x100.

The middle div is an image 400x400, shrunk to 50x50.

The bottom div is an image 50x50, enlarged to 100x100. - You can see "blurring" and pixelation.

CSS

```
.picturediv {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 4px solid blue;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.picturediv:nth-child(1) img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
.picturediv:nth-child(2) img {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
.picturediv:nth-child(3) img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```